# Accurately cut an .mp4 with ffmpeg without losing audio fidelity?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to find a way of *accurately* cutting an .mp4 with ffmpeg. As I understand, it will need to be re-encoded to get around the issue of keyframes. I know the video quality can be set to lossless with '-crf 0', but is there a means of doing this with the audio as well? The best attempt I have pieced together is this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i input.mp4 -t 23 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 320k -strict experimental -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mp4
```

I'm not too bothered about file size either. Thanks for any help.

*UPDATE using ffmpeg 3.2.5*

This produces a 13 second output video:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -i input.mp4 -t 10 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -crf 0 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

This produces a 10 second output (what I'm looking for) but without re-encoded audio:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:03 -i input.mp4 -t 10 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

*ANOTHER UPDATE*

I don't think this is possible, so as Brad suggested, I will look into using .mkv with VP9 encoding and PCM audio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand, it will need to be re-encoded to get around the issue of keyframes.

That's correct, and AAC audio has a framing problem as well.

If you want lossless audio, you need to use a codec that supports lossless audio.  I'd recommend FLAC.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info, but I'm building an electron app (:p) and chromium cannot play .mkv, or .avi. I tried 'webChimera' as a video plugin but that does not seem to have Linux support, damn

Comment: @ThomasHarker Chromium can absolutely play MKV.  That's essentially what the WebM format is.  If it isn't playing for you, your issue then is codec support.  Change to VP9 and Opus and you're good to go.  If you use those codecs, you might as well use strict WebM as well.

Comment: I've not heard of VP9.. sounds like the way to go, thanks. I don't know much about codec support, but I'm limited with whatever electron ships with. I can't really mark this as the right answer though...... or can I..

Comment: @ThomasHarker You also could use normal PCM audio in your MKV.  Bigger than FLAC, but more compatible.

Answer (score 0):

All audio frames are keyframes so audio can simply be copied over, as long as ffmpeg supports the audio codec in the output container.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i input.mp4 -t 23 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -preset ultrafast -crf 0 output.mp4
```

And if the video trim inpoint is a keyframe, so can the video. Since the video stream start (-ss 0) will start on a keyframe, you can use

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i input.mp4 -t 23 -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: I've just updated to ffmpeg 3.2.5 and it seems to behave slightly better... I will investigate, but I'm sure the audio needed to be re-encoded as well if you were not on a video keyframe.

Comment: hmm stranger still. with v3.2.5, if I include '-c:a copy' it snaps to the nearest keyframe and fails to cut accurately. Without, it seems to cut the video precisely according to '-t'. I thought the default behavior was 'copy' ?

Comment: *I'm sure the audio needed to be re-encoded as well if you were not on a video keyframe* - No, certainly not. Audio and video are independent essences. Default behaviour is to encode.

Comment: Ok, useful info, thanks, but this solution seems to still be re-encoding the audio so I don't think it is possible :(

Comment: With `-c:a copy` there's no audio encoding occurring. Either the audio will get copied or the command will abort.

Comment: @Mulvya The audio frame though isn't sample-accurate like it would be if it were PCM.  It's AAC in this case The audio has the same problem as the video... it needs to be re-encoded if there is a desire to have exact cutting.  Also don't forget about the bit reservoir.

Comment: Exact cutting in the context of video files means keeping all the audio corresponding to the video and preserving sync. There's usually no need for cleaving an audio frame. Unless one is concating a whole bunch of trimmed videos, that extra 10-15 ms of audio won't make a difference.

Comment: @Mulvya I'm curious... is it possible to cut losslessly by doing something hacky with the PTSs?  Leave data in the stream for audio and video on the nearest keyframe and independent audio frame, but set a presentation timestamp in a way that it only decodes and then doesn't appear until 00:00:00?